# Mathematica color schemes for the colorblind

Tags: graphics, color

Does *Mathematica* have a graphics option that makes plots intelligible for people with colorblindness?

Comment: Even if one is not colorblind, a plot might still not be intelligible as a result of poor presentation. There are many color schemes available but ultimately I think it is up to you to find a way to present your results clearly; there are no magic options to improve a plot's intelligibility for people with particular visual impairments.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A nice set of color-blind proof and print friendly color schemes can be find [here](http://www.sron.nl/~pault/) (see also the [pdf](http://www.sron.nl/~pault/colourschemes.pdf)). Actually, the distinct color scheme describe in the above links is not very different from the default *Mathematica* color set.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is this the _Mathematica_ default scheme or the scheme recommend for those with color-impaired vision?

Comment: I am not technically color blind, but I still have difficulties with this color scheme. I can not see the text I presume is displayed inside the octagon in the lower left corner. I infer it's there because I can see the others are labeled.

Comment: I am not convinced by this scheme. I think it does use too much redish and greenish colors, which from what I understand are hard to distinguish if you are color blind. I found [this](http://jfly.iam.u-tokyo.ac.jp/color/) helpful.

Comment: @m_goldberg As long as you can distinguish the colors of the octagons, you're fine. The black text inside the lower left octagon is barely readable because of the small difference in contrast.

Comment: @jenson The choice of colors is described in section 6 of the linked pdf. See also the new picture added to my answer.

Comment: @m_goldberg An answer to your first question: the pictures above are not the *Mathematica* default color scheme, they are taken from the docs they I linked in my answer.

Comment: @VLC I think it is a nice scheme, next to each other only the two "grays" seem to be very close, but similar colors like the darker blues seem to be to hard to distinguish if you can compare them directly (in a legend or something like that). In general it might be better to use less colors and rather different symbols/line styles (also usefull when it comes to naming the colors in a text)

Comment: @jenson I fully agree, data should be distinguished by colors, symbols and line styles to be always easily readable.

Comment: I am *not* fine. I have a diagnosed eye problem -- I can only distinguish color at much higher contrast levels than those with normal color vision. The text I referred to is not "barely readable" to me, it is invisible. The text in the dark red octagon at the right bottom qualifies as "barely readable" to my vision.

Comment: @m_goldberg What I meant is that the point of a color scheme for people with color-impaired vision is to *distinguish* the colors of the octagons, not to read the text. I've added another version of the same picture, maybe it helps.

Comment: Of course it helps. My point is that, when designing technical graphics, the designer should pay attention to contrast as well as hue.

Answer (score 9):

It looks like the new default plot colors in Mathematica 10 take into account colorblindness.

http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/enhanced-visualization/improved-styles-for-color-vision-impairment.html

Here's a screengrab from that page.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

My answer pertains mainly to color schemes as commonly used in Plot3D or DensityPlot rather than distinct curves in a regular Plot. The short answer is that the following three color schemes tend to be better than most schemes for everyone, including the color deficient: **SunsetColors**, **ThermometerColors**, and **LightTemperatureMap**. The right choice depends on what you're plotting.

I don't know for sure which color schemes are the best for the color deficient, but the [site](http://www.sron.nl/~pault/) mentioned in @VLC's answer says that sunset is better than a rainbow scheme. Note that the "sunset" on that site looks more like Mathematica's ThermometerColors or LightTemperatureMap.

```
ColorData["ThermometerColors", "Image"]
ColorData["LightTemperatureMap", "Image"]
```

[image]

[image]

Mathematica has several built-in ColorSchemes that you can find in the documentation page guide/ColorSchemes. You can view them all yourself by using the command ColorData and trying them out.

```
ColorData[]
(*
{"Gradients", "Indexed", "Named", "Physical"}
*)
```

Within each of these collections, there are several schemes.

```
Short[ColorData["Gradients"]]
(*
{AlpineColors,<<49>>,WatermelonColors}
*)
```

Try out a scheme with the following command:

```
ColorData["SunsetColors", "Image"]
```

[image: SunsetColors]

The best choice for you might depend on what you're plotting. For example, if you were showing an astronomical image, SunsetColors might be better because the areas with no flux would be black.

[image]

If you were making a geographical map of the Earth, having a blue/red scheme would probably be better.

[image]

Note that this [site](http://www.sron.nl/~pault/) shows that the trench near Japan is more visible to everyone with this blue/red scheme than in a visible spectrum scheme.

Comment: How is any of this relevant to the question, which was about "color schemes for the colorblind"?

Comment: Some schemes are better or worse for the color deficient. As stated in my answer and the site I referenced, these blue/red schemes are better than rainbow schemes for the color deficient. I gave some examples that are consistent with the recommendation of that site, and I included information on how to look at other schemes for those who don't even know where to look.