# Is there a way to make colorblind-safe color maps in Mathematica?

Tags: color

I was recently looking for contrast-uniform colormaps to produce a density plot for publication and among a bunch of nice resources (including in particular [this one](https://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html) and [this one](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/viridis/vignettes/intro-to-viridis.html)) I found a nice paper,

> Optimizing colormaps with consideration for color vision deficiency to enable accurate interpretation of scientific data, J.R. Nuñez, C.R. Anderton and R.S. Renslow, [arXiv:1712.01662](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.01662) (2017)

which describes an algorithm and python code to take some given color gradient and make it safe for use on print and on publications that will be viewed by the general public (thus including a several-percent fraction of readers with color vision deficiencies):

> We developed a Python module, cmaputil, to create [Color Vision Deficiency]-optimized colormaps, which imports colormaps and modifies them to be perceptually uniform in CVD-safe colorspace while linearizing and maximizing the brightness range

Is there some existing facility within Mathematica to do this type of task?

Comment: related: [Mathematica color schemes for the blind](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20851/125)

Comment: Mathematica version 10 has color styles that are more distinct for the color vision impaired, see the Wolfram article at [Improved Styles for Color Vision Impairment](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/enhanced-visualization/improved-styles-for-color-vision-impairment.html).

Comment: @creidhne Sure - but those are the discrete color lists used by the defaults of e.g. Plot. I'm looking for color *maps* for continuous variables.